# Using setSourceType with image picker up hides status bar

Tags: iphone

I am pretty sure this is a bug but I thought I would check.  I used the camera overlay to add a button so that on the iphone a user can switch from the camera view to the photo library.  When button is taped the source type switches fine but the status bar is missing from the photo library.  Throughout the rest of that session the status bar remains missing from all views evet thougth isStatusBarHidden reports NO.

This is how the camera overlay view is created

```
if (cameraOverlayView == nil) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CameraOverlayView" owner:self options:nil];
}
```

If camera is available this is when I set source type and add overlay

```
if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
    [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
    [imagePicker setCameraOverlayView:cameraOverlayView];
}
```

Here is the action statement to change source type.

- (IBAction)selectImage;
  {
  [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
  }

If I don't tap the button on the overlay there is no problem with the status bar.

PS. I did submit a bug report on this.

Comment: I'm experiencing what might be a related problem: the status bar disappears when showing the image picker with UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera. I want to show the camera, but overlay the translucent status bar on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by explicitly hiding and then showing the status bar:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
```